# Force LF line separators in .idea/* files

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, line-endings

Is there a way to force **LF line separators/endings** for the files inside the .idea folder (*.iml, *.xml) of JetBrains IDEs like pyCharm/IntelliJ on windows?

I already tried setting the "Line separators" setting in "File | Settings | Editor | Code Style" to "Unix and OS X (\n)" but this apparently only works for the source files, because after changing the files manually to LF they change back to CRLF when the IDE edits them.

Comment: Why do you care which separators these files have? These are the IDE's configuration files, and it's the IDE's business how it stores them.

Comment: They (and I) care because files in .idea/ are designed to be checked in and shared between developers and it's tedious to worry about CRLF in some checked in files but not others.